# Moving table inline-css out of HTML part

Tags: html, css, html-table, format

I was wondering if there's some way to somehow transfer all the inline-css on the table to the CSS file ? I guess that would require to identify each `<td>` seperately, but how can it be done? (maybe it's possible to use like `<td1>` `<td2>` etc.?

http://jsfiddle.net/NDYhL/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

    <table class="tableBot">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="507" style="text-align:left">Topic</th>
                            <th width="77" style="text-align:center">Responses</th>
                            <th width="0" style="text-align:center; ">Last message</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">FoofffffffftetadfgdfgdfgdfgstafgstFooffffffghfghfghfghfghfftetastastFoofffffffffffftetastast</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">329</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Jonas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">16</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Untanas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Foo</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">28</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Petras</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">324</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Untanas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">111</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Jonas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">546</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Untanas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">1</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Jonas</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="507" style="text-align:left">Bar</td>
                            <td width="77" style="text-align:center">97</td>
                            <td width="100" style="text-align:center">Petras</td>
                            <td width="110" style="text-align:center">19-03-2014 13:37</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1150px;
    font-size:16;
}

.content{

}

.tableBot{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-size:14px;
    width:795px;

}

.tableBot th{
    background:rgb(229,229,229);
    color:#555555;
}

.tableBot td{
   border:1px solid rgb(229,229,229); 

}
.tableBot tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:rgb(229,229,229);

}

.tableBot tbody{
    color:#555555;

}
```

Comment: give the th a colspan=2

Comment: awesome, thank You. What about getting rid of the inline-css part? Any easy way to 'index' the td's? (You should make this an answer, not a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can give the last th a colspan, you can't do it with css.

Addtionally, moving the syling to css is actually realy easy.

You can utilize the td:first-child and td:nth-child() pseudo selectors like this

```
table tr td:firstchild{width: 507px; text-align: left;}
table tr td:nth-child(2){ width: 77px; text-align:center;}
```

and go from there

Comment: Oh... Thanks again :D Had a little brain lag, thought that you cannot use nth-child on these tables.. sigh

Comment: why on earth would you not be able to?